# Laravel delete all posts except that i clicked

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, dashboard

I try to delete post by click on delete button, but I have problem. If i click on delete button, it delete all posts by that user except that post I've clicked on.
Whats the problem?

My routes.php:

```
Route::get('deletepost/{post_id}', 'PostController@getDeletePost')->name('delete');
```

My PostController:

```
public function getDeletePost($post_id){
  $post = Post::where('id', $post_id)->first();
    if(Auth::user() != $post->user){
      return redirect()->back();
    }
  $post->delete();
  return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message' => 'Successfully deleted!']);
}
```

My Post model:

```
public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

My User model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

    public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
   }
}
```

And dashboard:

```
@if(Auth::user() == $post->user)
            <a href="#">Edit</a>
            <a href=" {{ route('delete', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}">Delete</a>
@endif
```

I am using Laravel v5.2.39. Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `Post::where('id', $post_id)->first();` is not finding the post with the ID. Change it to `Post::where('id', $post_id)->firstOrFail();` and it will throw an exception, which you can catch (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException).